# How to set the fare on the km based in the fare_attributes.txt file

Tags: gtfs

I am new to the GTFS. I need to set the fare for the route based on the km.

For example

```
 1 km = 2USD
 2 km = 4USD
 3 km = 6USD
```

and so on.

How to set this on the fare_attribute.txt? I have to set each km fare on the fare_attribute.txt manually?

Comment: Please explain what you have already tried, what came out, and what you expected to see.

Comment: @PeterSmit Thanks for the reply. Actually i didn't understand the fare_attributes.txt fields fully. I have read the documentation on google transit. But i didn't get any way to start on fixing the fare based on the KM. And sorry for producing incomplete data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no simple way to set distance-based fares in GTFS. You will have to do it manually by explicitly setting the fare between every pair of stops.

Example 6 on this [Google Code page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/googletransitdatafeed/wikis/FareExamples.wiki) gives some of the flavor. To summarize that example, you will have to

1. define each stop as its own "zone" in `stops.txt`,
2. add a record in `fare_rules.txt` with a unique `fare_id` for every pair of stops specifying the `origin_id` and the `destination_id` of that stop pair, and
3. add a corresponding record with the same `fare_id` to `fare_attributes.txt` that specifies the exact price between that pair of stops.

This will of course result in very large `fare_rules.txt` and `fare_attributes.txt` files, which is pretty unpleasant. This might be a nice feature request for future GTFS schema changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer